# Help solving first-order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have first-order differential equation $$y=xy'+ \frac{1}{2}(y')^{2}$$ Maybe, with this someone will find way to solve it $$\frac{1}{2}y'(2x+y')=y$$ I thought I can use $x^2+y=t$ for subtitution and when I derivate, I have $t'=2x+y'\\(t'-2x)t'=2t-2x^2$ which is acctualy the same as previous. I don't have idea how to start..

Comment: This is a Clarauts equation. Try differentiating the equation with respect to $x$. You should be able to determine a general solution and a singular However, I haven’t actually worked it out as on mobile.

Comment: Spelled "Clairaut" if you want to find it in a search engine.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Rewrite like this: $$2y = 2xy'+y'^2$$ so adding $x^2$ on both sides we get $$2y+x^2 = x^2+2xy'+y'^2$$ or $$2y+x^2 = (x+y')^2$$

Let $z = 2y+x^2$ then $z' = 2y'+2x$, so $$4z =(z')^2\implies z'=\pm 2\sqrt{z} \implies z = (c\pm x)^2$$

So $$ y = {1\over 2}(z-x^2) =  {1\over 2}c^2\pm cx$$

Comment: It seems ok, but how to go back in equation?Do I need to express y and y' from these two substitution, and then go back on start and fin there z? Was this your idea?

Comment: Edit................

Comment: Your last conclusion is wrong, the linear solutions are $y'=a\implies y=ax+\frac12a^2$.

Comment: @LutzL Your $a$ is constant you get after integrate x? (like in many cases c)

Comment: @Figgaro : Yes. That follows more easily from the other approach, $y''(y'+x)=0$ implies that either $y'=c$ constant ($y=ax+b$ was in the answer before the last edit) or $y'=-x$ which can both be directly inserted into the original equation. Note that you can switch solution types where they are tangent, that is on the envelope $y=-\frac12x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiate both sides with respect to $x$:
$$y'=xy''+y'+y'y''$$ and then we get
$$y''(x+y')=0$$